# Rails simulate nested resources with basic views from same controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

If in views/abouts/ I have "index.html.haml" and  "history.html.haml".
How can I access to abouts#history which is a basic html page.

**From log I get this error, I guess it is processing it as a show, what can I do?:**

```
  Processing by AboutsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"history"}
  About Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `abouts`.* FROM `abouts` WHERE (`abouts`.`id` = 0) LIMIT 1

  ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find About with ID=history):
```

**routes.rb**

```
scope() do
  resources :abouts, :path => 'about-us' do
    match 'about-us/history' => "about-us#history"
  end
end
```

**abouts_controller.rb**

```
def history
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html

  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few problems. First, you should be matching `'history'` and not `'about-us/history'` (the route is nested so the `'about-us/'` part is automatically included). Second, you need to specify that the route should match the collection, not a member of the collection, with the `:on => :collection` option. Finally, you should be routing the match to `'abouts#history'` and not `'about-us#history'` (because the controller is named `abouts` regardless of what path string you use when routing).

So try this:

```
resources :abouts, :path => 'about-us' do
  match 'history' => "abouts#history", :on => :collection
end
```

Also note that `match` will match *all* HTTP requests: `POST` as well as `GET`. I'd suggest using `get` rather than `match`, to narrow the HTTP request type to just `GET` requests:

```
resources :abouts, :path => 'about-us' do
  get 'history' => "abouts#history", :on => :collection
end
```

Hope that helps.